# Teamviewer 9 cannot start on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, teamviewer

I've installed Teamviewer 9 (32bit / 64bit multiarch), and I've install wine1.6 on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64bit) but when I run teamviewer, I get this on the terminal:

```
root@waiylgeek:~# teamviewer
Init...
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
root@waiylgeek:~#
```

Any idea on how can this be fixed will be very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have noticed that since 12.04 LTS. The installation never worked to me, however, I run it without installation and works almost perfect. I connect to Windows and run DOS based applications. Many Ctrl+ key combinations do not work in DOS based apps whilst in the WIN based apps work. This may help -- http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx#other -- Check at the end of the page the heading "Run TeamViewer without installation".